# Linux Mint want to shrink the drive

Tags: linux

i want to srink the drive having linuxmint..
when i try to umount the drive that having limuxmint space 700gb through Gparted it showing message

"# umount -v "/" umount: /: target is busy         (In some cases useful info about processes that          use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to boot through a LIVECD for some sort.(ubuntu livecd for example)
you can not umount a volume that is busy (used by the operating system)

Comment: you mean i need to install linuxmint again with CD because i have installed it by usb before?
no another way to shrink the busy drive?

Comment: I mean to boot from a livecd or live usb without installing.
the live operating system will "see" your partitions and you will be able to change them as your please.